# How to load all records from JSON array into UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have been through the questions on here and tried some of the suggestions that others have been given, but none of them seem to work. Basically I have JSON data received from my webservice and that is populating an array that I then wish to put into a UITableViewCell. But my problem is that tableview cell displays only one record from my array. I need to display all my records as a list view to the user.

Here is my web service parsed JSON array:

```
    NSData *data = [soapResultsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0      error:nil];
    NSArray *planArray = [json objectForKey:@"plan_type"];
    NSLog(@"planArray==>%@",planArray);
    NSLog(@"planArrayCount==>%d",[planArray count]);
for (int i = 0 ; i<[planArray count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"print==>%d",i);
        recordResults = NO;
        appDelegate.nameString = [[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.ageString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.sexString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"sex"]objectAtIndex:i];
        appDelegate.deptString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"dept"]objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"name==%@,age==%@,sex==%@,dept==%@",appDelegate.nameString,appDelegate.ageString,appDelegate.sexString,appDelegate.deptString);

    }
```

Now here comes the tableview part. I have one view controller I placed Uitableview from outlet then I merged UITableViewCell from custom UITableViewCell.
Here is my tableview cell coding:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *mobPlan = (mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       if (mobPlan == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        mobPlan = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    mobPlan.nameLabel.text = appDelegate.nameString;
    mobPlan.ageLabel.text =appDelegate.ageString;
    mobPlan.sexLabel.text =appDelegate.sexString;
    mobPlan.deptLabel.text =appDelegate.sexString;

    return mobPlan;
}
```

So, can you show me how to load all data from my web service JSON into UITableViewCell?

Here is my NSLog output:

```
2015-01-07 10:41:00.145 AmslideMenu[430:5779] planArrayCount==>68
2015-01-07 10:41:00.145 AmslideMenu[430:5779] print==>0 
2015-01-07 10:41:00.146 AmslideMenu[430:5779]name==james,age==17,sex==male,dept==civil 
2015-01-07 10:41:00.146 AmslideMenu[430:5779] print==>1
2015-01-07 10:41:00.146 AmslideMenu[430:5779]name==rahul,age==17,sex==male ,dept==IT
2015-01-07 10:41:00.146 AmslideMenu[430:5779]print==>2 
2015-01-07 10:41:00.146 AmslideMenu[430:5779]name==ramesh,age==18,sex==male,dept==Mechanic
```

Comment: Check the - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: `[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]` is `array` or `dictionary`?

Comment: You assigned this to an array. And in `for` loop you call `valueForKey` for the same.

Comment: Also you didn't keep values separately. You are just changing the values of same property. How can you get all data then?

Comment: json is an dictionary and planArray is an array

Comment: Please provide JSON data format, that will help others to understand are you doing right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a property first to keep data,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
```

Create a `NSObject` subclass to represent a set of properties like name, age and all.

```
@interface User : NSObject

// Properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;

@end
```

Then create `User` object in for loop and add it in `dataArray`

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<[planArray count]; i++) {

    recordResults = NO;
    User *user = [User alloc] init];
    user.nameString = [[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:i];
    user.ageString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:i];
    user.sexString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"sex"]objectAtIndex:i];
    user.deptString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"dept"]objectAtIndex:i];

    [_dataArray addObject:user];
}
```

Then access that array to populate tableView.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

```
mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *mobPlan = (mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   if (mobPlan == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    mobPlan = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

User *user = [_dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
mobPlan.nameLabel.text = user.nameString;
mobPlan.ageLabel.text = user.ageString;
mobPlan.sexLabel.text = user.sexString;
mobPlan.deptLabel.text = user.sexString;

return mobPlan;
}
```

Comment: mam i tried that method also, value is getting correctly but when i populate in UItableview cell jam getting only one records thats the problem

Comment: @Anand- You are accessing same one `appDelegate` property. How can you get all the data?

Comment: okie now i got idea let me try ur Answer and will reply back is there any issue and Thank u for ur time, god bless

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened because you don't understand the how to store values and the tableview's dataSource.

Maybe your datasource and the tableview are separated.

You should store values into an array,  like you did now, you can declare an array in the appDelegate.

@property NSArray *planTypes;

When you did this ,you can change to

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:planArray.count];
for (int i = 0 ; i<[planArray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"print==>%d",i);
    recordResults = NO;
    NSString *nameString = [[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"name"]objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *ageString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"age"]objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *sexString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"sex"]objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *deptString=[[[json valueForKey:@"plan_type"]valueForKey:@"dept"]objectAtIndex:i];
    generally, we create n modelClass like STPerson {@property name, xxx...},and value the person
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name":nameString, @"age":ageString,...};
    [dataSource addObject:dictionary];
}
the most important comes:
// you store values into appDelegate
appDelegate.planTypes = dataSource;
```

after you store values, you should override some methods from UITableViewDataSource

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return appDelegate.planTypes.count;
}
```

modify your cellForRow Method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *mobPlan = (mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (mobPlan == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mobilePlanDetailsCellTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        mobPlan = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary *plan = appDelegate.planTypes[indexPath.row];

    mobPlan.nameLabel.text = plan[@"name"];
    mobPlan.ageLabel.text = plan[@"age"];
    mobPlan.sexLabel.text = plan[@"sex"];
    mobPlan.deptLabel.text = plan[@"dept"];

    return mobPlan;
}
```

Comment: you should understand above two methods. when you custom your tableview cell, you should set a newValue. If you want to show more than one cell, you should tell the tableview how many cell it has by the method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: i think ur answer will help me, first i need to create an array in AppDelegate.h ?

Comment: @Anand- Just declare an array as a property.The purpose doing this is sharing values between different objects.There are many ways share values,  you can do like that.

Comment: i tried ur method its good but my tableview cell does't showed any values

Comment: what's your json content

Comment: u asking my json string ?

Comment: @Anand-You can set a breakpoint to get the appDelegate.planTypes.count after you set the value.and make sure after you set the value, you send reloadData message to your tableview. if you have sent message, cellForRow and numberOfRows will be called. and maybe you should tell us your json string

Comment: my json string is:{"plan_type":[{"name”:"anand","age”:"16","sex”:"male:"dept”:"IT"},{"name”:"gotham","age”:"18","sex":"sex : male","dept”:"IT"},{"name”:"revathy","age”:”16","sex”:"female","dept”:"csc"}

Comment: after you store values into an array, is the array empty?. and have the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: been called ? If not, you should call tableView reloadData after your web services finished.

Comment: yes the array didn't  stored and also tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: been called didn't called :(\

Comment: the problem is tat the array what we stored its not getting called in tableview cell can u give any alternate solution ?

Comment: If not, you should call tableView reloadData after your web services finished.

Comment: i checked:- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
in this method my array count is getting displayed

Comment: but : - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{ return appdelegate.plantype.count;} its return nil

Comment: you can check your appdelegate == nil